# Daily/Weekly/Monthly Active Users in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

**I have two tables:**

`table1` contains a list of unique user ids (user_id) with a timestamp for every date they logged in (date)

```
table1
-------------------
user_id | date
-------------------
User123 | 22/3/2021
User456 | 23/3/2021
User789 | 23/3/2021
User456 | 24/3/2021
User456 | 25/3/2021
User789 | 30/3/2021
```

`table2` contains a list of dates with total users registered on each date (cum_registered_users)

```
table2
----------------------
date      | cum_users
---------------------
22/3/2021 |   1
23/3/2021 |   3
24/3/2021 |   3
25/3/2021 |   4
26/3/2021 |   5
27/3/2021 |   5
28/3/2021 |   5
29/3/2021 |   5
30/3/2021 |   5
```

**What do I want to calculate:**

For the same list of dates in table2, I want to know the distinct number of users who logged in that day (Daily Active Users), within the 7 days (Weekly Active Users) and within the last 30 days (Monthly Active Users) - all as a percentage of cum_users on that date

Desired output for 7d Active Users:

```
date      | 7d_AU | DAU
---------------------
22/3/2021 |   1   |  100%
23/3/2021 |   3   |  100%
24/3/2021 |   3   |  100%
25/3/2021 |   3   |  75%
26/3/2021 |   3   |  60%
27/3/2021 |   3   |  60%
28/3/2021 |   3   |  60%
29/3/2021 |   3   |  60%
30/3/2021 |   2   |  40%
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Your schema doesn't support querying historical active users. If you're looking at a `table2` row from a year ago, there may not be any `table1` rows with a last login date in the month before that date, because all of those users have logged in again since, and so that data is lost.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired out put

Comment: @BlueStar thanks for the comment - you're quite right. I've updated the schema in the post above - does this allow us to continue?

Comment: @eshirvana thanks for your comment - I've added more detail to the post above if you're able to help?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little awkward, but you can fit both of those timespans into one query by adding in a secondary filter in the select:

```sql
SELECT 
  table2.date,
  cum_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT table1.user_id) 
    FILTER (WHERE table1.date > table2.date - interval '7 days') 
    AS weekly_active_users,
  (100.0 * 
    COUNT(DISTINCT table1.user_id) 
    FILTER (WHERE table1.date > table2.date - interval '7 days') / cum_users
  )::int::text || '%' AS weekly_active_users_percent,
  COUNT(DISTINCT table1.user_id) AS monthly_active_users,
  (100.0 * 
    COUNT(DISTINCT table1.user_id) / cum_users
  )::int::text || '%' AS monthly_active_users_percent
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON (table1.date <= table2.date AND table1.date > table2.date - interval '30 days')
GROUP BY table2.date, table2.cum_users
ORDER BY table2.date;
```

Comment: Amazing - thank you! So I think it works great in my data set the only question I have - should the interval here be 6 days as we're doing <= and >= (i.e. or we do 7 day interval with <= and >). Therefore we'd also do 29 days for 30d rolling. Is there a simple way to add 30d into the same report?

Comment: @Ross I edited my answer to include both timespans into the same query. And yes, one of the inequalities should not be inclusive.